# The conditions don't work in the React render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
   console.log("render")
         return (
      <div className="cont">

{() => {
  console.log("works!")

if(condition)
return(<div className="btnnav" onClick={(event) => this.change(event)} 
></div>)

}}
```

I try to put a condition inside the return but appear this error
[image]

Comment: you are using iife in a wrong way, also you can avoid that and directly use ternary operator for conditional rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this:

```js
render() {
  return (
      <div className="cont">
      { condition && <div className="btnnav" onClick={(event) => this.change(event)}></div> }
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, you're telling React to print a function, which doesn't really make sense.

You need to call the function:

```
{(() => { ... return ...}())}
```